# Problemas con el responsive en JavaScript y jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Tengo un problema de responsive en una página web. Lo que pasa es que estoy agregando un *sandbox* y en ese mismo un `iframe` y me sale cortado, es decir, no se visualiza completamente.

Éste es el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.14/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <p id="callback"></p>
  <iframe src="https://www.strategis.mx/Glocator/" name="mainaccFrame" onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);" id="mainaccFrame" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100px" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-modals allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups"></iframe>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.14/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    iFrameResize({
      log: true, // Enable console logging
      enablePublicMethods: true, // Enable methods within iframe hosted page
    });

    function resizeIframe(obj) {
      console.log("datos funcion\n " + obj);
      obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
      obj.style.width = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        var viewportheight;
        $('#mainaccFrame').attr('height', viewportheight * .95 + "px");
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Y así se ve cortado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No tenemos mucha informacion de tu problema, si puedes poner tu codigo **HTML** seria mas facil entender tu duda

Comment: Hola, perfecto es lo que hare en este momento, editare la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por sus respuestas, al final mis compañeros de trabajo dejaron este codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/comun/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>




<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>-->


<!-- CSS -->
<!--<link href="estilos-responsive/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
<!--<link href="estilos-responsive/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
<!--<link href="estilos-responsive/css/lightbox-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->


</head>





<!-- ======== JS ======== -->
<script  src="/comun/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="/comun/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script  src="/comun/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body style="margin: 0px;">
<!--<p id="callback"></p>-->
<p id="callback"></p>
<iframe src="https://www.strategis.mx/Glocator/" name="iframe_re" onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);" id="iframe_re" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="100%"></iframe>

<script src="/comun/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/comun/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>   

<script>
var viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
$('#iframe_re').css('height', viewportheight*.95+"px");
iFrameResize({
                log                     : true,                  // Enable console logging
                enablePublicMethods     : true,                  // Enable methods within iframe hosted page
            });

function resizeIframe(obj)
{
    console.log("datos funcion\n "+ obj);
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    obj.style.width = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        var viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
        $('#iframe_re').css('height', viewportheight*.95+"px");
    });

    $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
        if(window.orientation==0)
        {
            popup-content(){
                //Me quede aqui


            }
        }



  alert("The orientation has changed!");
});
});








</script>



 </body>
 </html>
```

No se llego a la meta deseada, ya que el problema era del gestor de contenido que vendria siendo Tridion, y pues ahi les deje mi aporte del codigo.

De antemano les mando un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que utilices medidas como ***vw*** - **v**iewport **w**idth  o  ***vh*** - **v**iewport **h**eight que son responsive o bien el famoso  **%**

De ese modo no tienes que usar ni *px* ni Jquery ni JS para responsive

Sin embargo vi que, por tu código, sabes esto así que supongo lo quieres hacer con JQuery y aquí va (por cierto los atributos width y height ya son un poco obsoletos la W3C recomienda cambiarlos por style):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.14/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <p id="callback"></p>
  <iframe src="https://www.strategis.mx/Glocator/" name="mainaccFrame" onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);" id="mainaccFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 100%;" sandbox="allow-modals allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups"></iframe>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.14/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
  <script>
iFrameResize({
  log: true, // Enable console logging
  enablePublicMethods: true, // Enable methods within iframe hosted page
});

function resizeIframe(obj) {
  console.log("datos funcion\n " + obj);
  obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  obj.style.width = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
    $('#mainaccFrame').height(viewportheight * .5 + "px");
  });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hacía falta un valor para la variable *viewportheight*, estaba declarada pero no tenía ningún valor

Lo único que le haría falta es que no se hace responsive sino hasta que se llama a resize, por lo que podrías usar las medidas antes mencionadas o bien, poner otra función con `body onload="funcion()"` que haga exactamente lo mismo que resize.

O también podrías poner un `window.document.onload()` como tú quieras.

Answer (score 0):

Y aquí está con css y vh

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
  <p id="callback"></p>
  <iframe src="https://www.strategis.mx/Glocator/" name="mainaccFrame" onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);" id="mainaccFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 100%; height: 60vh;" sandbox="allow-modals allow-top-navigation allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups"></iframe>
  </body>
  </html>
```